# Z3: How to acces variables from model() without using hard-coded index?

Tags: c++, z3

Here is an example code I have written to get all possible solutions.

```
#include"z3++.h"

using namespace z3;
using namespace std;

int main() {

    context c;
    expr X = c.int_const("x");
    expr Y = c.int_const("y");
    expr Z = c.int_const("z");

    solver s(c);
    s.add(X == Y + Z);
    s.add((X > 0) && (Y > 0) && (Z > 0));
    s.add(X <= 10);


    int j = 1;
    while (s.check() == sat)
    {
        model m = s.get_model();

        cout << "solution " << j << " :" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++)
        {
            func_decl f1 = m[i];
            cout << f1.name() << " = " << m.get_const_interp(f1) << endl;
        }
        j++;

        s.add((Y != m.get_const_interp(m[1])) || (Z != m.get_const_interp(m[0])) || (X != m.get_const_interp(m[2])));
    }
}
```

Initially with help of print statements I was able to figure out that X,Y,Z values can be accessed using 2,1,0 index from model().

Is there any other way of doing it, where I don't need hard-coded index ?

Comment: "how to get all possible solutions?" ... "here is my code to get all possible solutions" it is not completely clear in what way your code is not doing what you want it to do

Answer (score 2):

Instead of referring to indexes, you should instead use an expression vector and add a blocking clause by iterating over your variables. Something like this should work:

```
#include"z3++.h"

using namespace z3;
using namespace std;

int main() {

    context c;
    expr X = c.int_const("x");
    expr Y = c.int_const("y");
    expr Z = c.int_const("z");

    solver s(c);
    s.add(X == Y + Z);
    s.add((X > 0) && (Y > 0) && (Z > 0));
    s.add(X <= 10);

    expr_vector myVars(c);
    myVars.push_back(X);
    myVars.push_back(Y);
    myVars.push_back(Z);

    int j = 1;
    while (s.check() == sat)
    {
        model m = s.get_model();
        expr_vector blocker(c);

        cout << "solution " << j << " :" << endl;
        for(expr v : myVars)
        {
            cout << v << " = " << m.eval(v) << endl;
            blocker.push_back(v != m.eval(v));
        }
        j++;

        s.add(mk_or(blocker));
    }
}
```

Assuming you put this in a file called `a.cpp`, compile it like this:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 a.cpp -lz3
```

I'll elide the output, but when I run the generated executable it prints 45 different solutions, which matches your original output.

Comment: odd that we get so similar questions at the same time. +1 :)

Comment: @PatrickTrentin Doing "get all solutions" in all languages for z3 should be a FAQ somewhere that we can simply point to. :-)

Comment: some time ago S.O. introduced WIKIs as a complementary resource here on this board. I haven't played with this feature yet, but you might actually be able to write the FAQ in a way that it becomes easily accessible. ;)